# Tables not mapped error, after clicking 'Generate DB from Model'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, ado.net, edmx

Working in VS2010.  I added 4 columns to a table in the database, then opened the project edmx file to 'Update from the Database'using the built in link.  By accident, I clicked 'Generate Database from Model'.  I redid the 'Update Model from Database' but it did not update.  I tried rebuilding but then I got an error:

Error   1   Error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - PersonAlias, Waiver, v_LocationsAlphabetical, Identification, RestrainingOrderData, CivilCompromiseData, DiversionData, FelonyData, PendingOffenseData, ViolationData, PreviousLocation, RequestedVolunteerData, History, Person. C:_VS Projects\entity.edmx 523 9   myApp

It is saying all the tables are not mapped.  I assume a duplicate database or something was created when I hit that 'generate database' button.  Where is it?  How do I get rid of it?

Comment: I never found a solution to this, so I restored the edmx and designer.cs files from backup.  I never ran the script that is generated by the 'create db from model' link, so I still have no idea what happened.  Thank GNU for backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click Generate database from Model it only creates SQL script which you have to execute first. You should also not combine Generate Database from Model and Update Model from Database. Use only one of these approaches.